# What is the idiom "...and roses"

Tags: idioms, metaphors

What is the idiom meaning not everything will be perfect, which ends "it's not all....and roses" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's not all sunshine and roses.**

Reference:  https://lyricstranslate.com/en/its-not-all-sunshine-and-roses

I googled 'wine and roses', thinking that might be what you were looking for and pulled up numerous other 'x' and roses pairs, e.g., peaches and roses, etc.

Comment: This could be a high-scoring answer with just a bit more effort! Links sometimes get broken, so it's important for the quality of our site that you include detail from the link as evidence that your answer is correct. It's ok to quote directly from the source, provided you use quotation marks or format it as blockquote. Use the [edit] link to add the detail. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic expression is:

***[be (not) all moonlight and roses](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+moonlight+and+roses)***:

> - To be very enjoyable and pleasant, especially of a romantic situation. ***This phrase is often used in the negative to emphasize difficulties in a romantic relationship.***
> - I thought that dating an actress would be all moonlight and roses, but she travels so much that I hardly ever see her. Living with a boyfriend or girlfriend is not all moonlight and roses, you know.

(The Free Dictionary)